# Google Analytics Code for different cross domains

Tags: google-analytics

I have one primary domain that is

**www.abc.tv**

and 2 sub-domains of other secondary domain

**1- blog.xyz.com**
**2- news.xyz.com**

Now i want view all states as single account which is **www.abc.tv**, so what changes i have to do in my Google analytic code?

OR

I just copy paste same code on all three sites and it will show accurate results?

Thanks & Regards,
Afshaan

Comment: I think you're better off leaving the trackers individual and perhaps looking at Analytics Premium (http://analytics.blogspot.dk/2014/05/google-analytics-premium-launches.html) which allows you to roll up data into a single view.

Comment: Will users switch between domains during a single session ? In that case you'd need to adapt your code for cross domain tracking. If these are separate sites that will be tracked in one account (not necessarily a good idea) you can simply drop in the same code in all pages (metrics for similar page urls on the different domains will be aggregated into one row if you do this).

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, dropping 100k for Analytics Premium just to get rollup reporting is probably overkill. You can filter the views by hostname and have an unfiltered view for all domains, which is in effect a poor mans rollup view.